# Which tokenizer can do word tokenization and span tokenization effectively?

Tags: python, tokenize

I have a sequence consisting of several sentences. I wish to find an effective tool to do word tokenization and span tokenization (find the character indices in the sequence, sometimes it's called offset.). I tried `TreebankWordTokenizer`, and found it treats the whole sequence as one sentence. Only the last dot can be separated. Here is an example:

```
from nltk.tokenize import TreebankWordTokenizer
s = "I love apples. You love pears."
l = TreebankWordTokenizer().span_tokenize(s)
print(l)
ts = [s[start:end] for start, end in TreebankWordTokenizer().span_tokenize(s)]
print(ts)
```

It returns:

```
[(0, 1), (2, 7), (8, 15), (16, 19), (20, 24), (25, 30), (30, 31)]
['I', 'love', 'apples.', 'You', 'love', 'pears', '.']
```

As you see in the third token the dot is not separated.

I also tried `nltk.word_tokenize(s)`. It can separate all the punctuations, but it has no span tokenization.

Please recommend some tokenizers that has both functions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `word_tokenize()` expects only a single sentence.  For your example, you can try using `sent_tokenize()` first.

```py
from nltk import sent_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import TreebankWordTokenizer

s = "I love apples. You love pears."
ss = sent_tokenize(s)
ts = [src[start:end] for tok, src in zip(TreebankWordTokenizer().span_tokenize_sents(ss), ss) for start, end in tok]
print(ts)
```

Output

```py
['I', 'love', 'apples', '.', 'You', 'love', 'pears', '.']
```